# create comparison form in Yii2

Tags: php, forms, view, yii2

I am using Yii2 Advanced Template.

I need to create a view for product comparison. view have same dependent dropdown two time in separate section. like this

**input fields in first section:**

category dropdown

subdategory dropdown(depends on category selected value)

sub-subdategory dropdown(depends on category and subdategory selected values)

**input fields in second section:**

same as first section

only one button for submit all data for comparison.

is there any plugin in Yii2 for the said task? or optimum approach

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is extension for this purpose called `Dependent Dropdown`. It's a part of this [extension set](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widgets).

- [Official Github page](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop)
- [Documentation](http://plugins.krajee.com/dependent-dropdown)
- [Demo](http://plugins.krajee.com/dependent-dropdown/demo)

Comment: thank you for your reply, I am asking about extension of comparison  form of same data fields. this extension work fine for only first section,not in second section

Comment: It's not absolutely clear from your question. If you need extension for comparison functionality too I can't remember anything related. It's more CMS functionality and there is no "optimum approach". It highly depends on your data structure and exact functionality you want to achieve. You didn't mention these details in the question. Anyways I recommend to look at Yii 2 based CMS, maybe you will find something similar and useful https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=yii2+cms I can't advise specific one because I didn't have any experience with them.